# Speaker diarization with Node js using openai

Tags: node.js, speech-to-text

I am developing whisper transcription in the node js using openai API. I am able to get the transcriptions for chunked files using ffmpeg library. I am struggling at the point of speaker diarization with node js. It would be great if get any guidance on this.

Comment: I'm also working on this, and whisper-cpp has a yet to be released feature on the master branch https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/pull/1058 - it separates speakers but does not identify them